# for line in open(filename)

Tags: python, file, garbage-collection

I frequently see python code similar to

```
for line in open(filename):
    do_something(line)
```

When does filename get closed with this code?

Would it be better to write

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        do_something(line)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`filename` would be closed when it falls out of scope. That normally would be the end of the method.

Yes, it's better to use `with`.

> Once you have a file object, you perform all file I/O by calling methods of this object. [...] When you are done with the file, you should finish by calling the `close` method on the object, to close the connection to the file:
>
> ```
> input.close()
> ```
>
> In short scripts, people often omit this step, as Python automatically closes the file when a file object is reclaimed during garbage collection (which in mainstream Python means the file is closed just about at once, although other important Python implementations, such as Jython and IronPython, have other, more relaxed garbage collection strategies). Nevertheless, it is good programming practice to close your files as soon as possible, and it is especially a good idea in larger programs, which otherwise may be at more risk of having excessive numbers of uselessly open files lying about. Note that `try`/`finally` is particularly well suited to ensuing that a file gets closed, even when a function terminates due to an uncaught exception.

<sub>*[Python Cookbook, Page 59.](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=1Shx_VXS6ioC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=garbage+collection+python+file+open&source=bl&ots=BB6-bAT8Q2&sig=w3L8P8EOVDQ-HS6NlBWdXdiN-kk&hl=es&ei=GgO9SvaJIdWPtgfU-8yKAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2#v=onepage&q=garbage%20collection%20python%20file%20open&f=false)*</sub>

Comment: I think you mean `f` instead of `filename` in "`filename` would be closed..."

Comment: I meant that the object created with `open(filename)` would be closed when it falls out of scope, i.e., when the iteration ends.

Comment: It would be closed when the for loop ends or at the end of the relevant method?

Comment: Depends on the GC, but I believe that its closed when the loop ends on CPython (later will check when is it being GCd)

Comment: @EstebanKüber I still don't understand why it's better to use "with". It seems the first method also closes the connection automatically once the loop ends normally or abnormally. Could you please explain more? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

Drop `.readlines()`. It is redundant and undesirable for large files (due to memory consumption). The variant with `'with'` block always closes file.

```
with open(filename) as file_:
    for line in file_:
        do_something(line)
```

When file will be closed in the bare `'for'`-loop variant depends on Python implementation.

Comment: Dex mentioned eliminating readlines() a while back.

>>depends on Python implementation>> That could be why different people are giving different answers.

Answer (score 9):

The `with` part is better because it close the file afterwards.
You don't even have to use `readlines()`. `for line in file` is enough.

I don't think the first one closes it.

Answer (score 3):

python is garbage-collected - cpython has reference counting and a backup cycle detecting garbage collector.

File objects close their file handle when the are deleted/finalized.

Thus the file will be eventually closed, and in cpython will closed as soon as the for loop finishes.