# how can I take an specific line in big file which has many similar lines, using python?

Tags: python, text, readline

have different files with same name, in different directories. In these files there are lines which are almost equal, I would like to take out only the last line of these ones( there are more lines after it) and write it in another file.

So far what I have done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

def cd_grep():
   for file in os.listdir("."):
     if os.path.isfile(file):
       for line in open("graph.txt"):
                  if " 4.49" in line:                               
                       line_list=[line] 
   g = open('comparation','a') 
   g.write ("%s" % (line[0:4]))
   g.close()
os.chdir('4.294')
cd_grep()
os.chdir(os.pardir)
os.chdir('4.394')
cd_grep()
os.chdir(os.pardir)
os.chdir('4.494')
cd_grep()
os.chdir(os.pardir)
os.chdir('4.594')
cd_grep()
os.chdir(os.pardir)
os.chdir('4.694')
cd_grep()
```

I've created a list because I am gonna take only a specific information of the whole line.

Finally I got that this procedure only works for small files and only if the last line of the file contains the term I'm searching.
For big files, I got this message ( inside the file, which I was hoping to get the line):
                 Voluntary context switches:         3403

Any idea or suggestion will be very appreciate.

Comment: First of all format your code so it is readable and properly indented.

Comment: Ok, thanks. First time I submitted a question out here. I hope it is better now.

Comment: Now show the exact error you get.  Is it an exception?  Does your program finish?  Where do you see that message?

Comment: I got the error inside the file, where I was hoping to get the line.
I don't know if it is an exception ( because I don't know exactly what its means). The program finish.

Comment: Are you sure that line `for line in open("graph.txt")` is correctly indented and why are you going through all files in directory if you are only interested in "graph.txt"?

Comment: @Juha Autero, It wasn't indented correctly here, thanks.
I thought it was the right way. Please tell me a better way.

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't closing your files.  See my answer below or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478697/for-line-in-openfilename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the error you are receiving (after your last edit).

I have tried to rewrite the code a bit, hope it gives you a result similar to what you need (WARNING: not tested).

```
with open ('comparation', 'a') as write_file:
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for filename in [f for f in files if f == "graph.txt"]:
      filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, filename))
      with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
          if " 4.49" in line:
            last = line
        write_file.write("File: %s, Line: %s\n" % (filepath, last[0:4]))
```

Comment: It worked pretty well. The only problem was, for some reason, it gives me the same, output, many times.
File: /path1/ , line:xxxxxx
File: /path1/ , line:xxxxxx
File: /path1/ , line:xxxxxx
File: /path1/ , line:xxxxxx
File: /path2/ , line:yyyyyy
File: /path2/ , line:yyyyyy
File: /path2/ , line:yyyyyy
File: /path2/ , line:yyyyyy

Should I, write the file(comparation) outside the loop?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot test it. I think you should be able to experiment with it at the interactive python interpreter; without test dirs/files I cannot answer you well. I have also forgotten to add "\n" when appending to the file (added now), which seems to have made one long line in the write_file. Hope it works better now; have fun tweaking it.

Comment: I am so sorry. I didn't delete the two first lines of my code. After doing that worked perfect.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you aren't closing your files.

```
def cd_grep():
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if os.path.isfile(file):
           graph_file = open('graph.txt'):
           for line in graph_file:
               if " 4.49" in line:                               
                   line_list=[line] 
           graph_file.close()
    g = open('comparation','a') 
    g.write ("%s" % (line[0:4]))
    g.close()
```

Or much better use `with` to open (and always close) your files.

```
def cd_grep():
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if os.path.isfile(file):
           with open('graph.txt') as graph_file:
               for line in graph_file:
                   if " 4.49" in line:                               
                       line_list=[line] 
    with open('comparation','a') as g:
        g.write ("%s" % (line[0:4]))
```

Comment: thanks you very much for attention and tips.
still it's taking the last line of the file, even it isn't the correct line.