# How do I close a file object I never assigned to a variable?

Tags: python, file, resources

```
from sys import argv
script, origin, destination = argv

open(destination, 'w').write(open(origin).read())
```

How do I close the destination and origin file objects? Or is this something I don't need to worry about?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478697/for-line-in-openfilename

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short straightforward scripts you shouldn't worry about these issues, but in bigger programs you might run out of file descriptors.

Since version 2.5, Python has [with](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement, which can do the file closing for you:

```
from __future__ import with_statement # Only required for Python 2.5
with open(destination, 'w') as dest:
   with open(origin) as orig:
        dest.write(orig.read())
```

Comment: **Note:** If you're using Python 2.5 you need to do `from __future__ import with_statement` at the *top* of the file.

Comment: Is the memory freed once the script has concluded?

Comment: @MonteCarloGenerator: What memory? This example basically reads data from one stream and writes it to another. And after you exit the `with` blocks, the file descriptors for `dest` and `orig` are closed.