# How do I close a file I didn't assign to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The solution to the following link did not solve my issue: [How do I close a file object I never assigned to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426978/how-do-i-close-a-file-object-i-never-assigned-to-a-variable)

How do I close the file in the following line?

```
file = open(filename, 'r').read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Why did it not solve your issue?

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you want to avoid the `with` statement in this case (as per the last question)?  It may not be on one line, but you don't have to worry about closing the file...

Comment: The solution in the linked question actually is the best answer.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946134/in-python-how-can-i-open-a-file-and-read-it-on-one-line-and-still-be-able-to-c/10946193#10946193.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I close a file object I never assigned to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426978/how-do-i-close-a-file-object-i-never-assigned-to-a-variable)

Comment: You rewrite the above code so you have access to the object to close it.  Or use `with`.

Comment: This is really a silly question. You already know how to close a file. So you're asking, "How can I deliberately avoid closing a file—but close it anyway?" Maybe the best answer is to write the correct code but then trick yourself into believing you wrote the incorrect code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a file is automatically garbage collected and closed. However, this pattern should generally be avoided. Instead, use the `with` statement:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
    lines = fd.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: I would avoid using `file` as a variable name. Other than that, this is a good answer.

Comment: Also, if you don't use `with` or if you don't explicitly `close()` a file object, It is not guaranteed to be garbage collected, especially if the script exits unexpectedly.

Comment: @JoelCornett - If the script exits unexpectedly, the process goes away, which implies that all open file descriptors will be closed.

Comment: @twalberg: That's certainly not guaranteed by Python. Of course it's true on every modern desktop or server OS… but Python runs (or at least has run) on platforms (like Classic Mac), where open files don't get closed when a process goes away.