# How to take floats from a txt to a Python list as strings

Tags: python, string, list

I am very new at programming. I have the following problem.

I want to take some floats from a .txt file, and add them to a Python list as strings, with a comma between them, like this:

```
.TXT:
194220.00   38.4397984  S   061.1720742 W   0.035
194315.00   38.4398243  S   061.1721378 W   0.036
```

Python:

```
myList = ('38.4397984,061.1720742','38.4398243,061.1721378')
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: It generally helps you to get better answers if you are able to show what you've tried to this point. A minor nitpick: `myList` is being declared as a tuple. Have a look at the `csv` module for some ideas of how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three key pieces you'll need to do this. You'll need to know how to [open files](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open), you'll need to know how to [iterate through the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478697/for-line-in-openfilename) with the file open, and you'll need to know how to [split the list](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Once you know all these things, it's as simple as concatenating the pieces you want and adding them to your list.

```
my_list = []
with open('path/to/my/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        my_list.append(words[1] + words[3])
print mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a method open(fileName, mode) that returns a file object.
fileName is a string with the name of the file.
mode is another a string that states how will the file used. Ex 'r' for reading and 'w' for writing.

```
f = open(file.txt, 'r')
```

This will create file object in the variable f. f has now different methods you can use to read the data in the file. The most common is f.read(size) where size is optional

```
text = f.read()
```

Will save the data in the variable text.

Now you want to split the string. String is an object and has a method called split() that creates a list of words from a string separated by white space.

```
myList = text.split()
```

In your code you gave us a tuple, which from the variable name i am not sure it was what you were looking for. Make sure to read the difference between a tuple and a list. The procedure to find a tuple is a bit different.