# How to take floats from a txt to a Python list as strings to answer questions?

Tags: python, string, list

questions:

```
.TXT:
194220.00   38.4397984  S   061.1720742 W   0.035
194315.00   38.4398243  S   061.1721378 W   0.036
```

Python:

```
myList = ('38.4397984,061.1720742','38.4398243,061.1721378')
```

Answer questions. [How to take floats from a txt to a Python list as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336056/how-to-take-floats-from-a-txt-to-a-python-list-as-strings)

code:

```
with open('haha.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        print words
        my_list.append(words[1] + words[3])
```

My test code doesn't produce the desired result. What is wrong with it? I am missing the `,`...

```
['38.4397984061.1720742', '38.4398243061.1721378']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the very obvious:

```
my_list.append(words[1] + "," + words[3])
```

?

Btw, small remark: Maybe it would have been more reasonable to ask this as a comment to the answer you already accepted in the other thread instead of opening another question.

Comment: Alas, what he wrote would not fit very good in a comment. Let alone the code, which cannot be formatted properly...

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you want, but I think

```
my_list.append((words[1], words[3]))
```

adds a tuple to `my_list`, so the result should be

```
[('38.43979840', '061.1720742'), ('38.43982430', '061.1721378')]
```

Instead, you could as well do

```
my_list.append((float(words[1]), float(words[3])))
```

to convert the strings representing numbers to numbers:

```
[(38.4397984, 61.1720742), (38.4398243, 61.1721378)]
```