# python search in text file

Tags: python, file, search

i want to search for a variable "elementid" in a txt file

```
  f = open("wawi.txt", "r")
  r = f.read()
  f.close()
  for line in r:
      if elementid in line:
          print("elementid exists")
          break
```

the elementid is maybe 123456

the txt contains three lines:

```
1235
56875
123456
```

but the code does not print "elementid exists", why ?
I work with python 3.4

Comment: do this instead: `for line in f:`

Comment: Sorry, misdiagnosed. See answer.

Comment: @mshsayem: Better yet: `with open('wawi.txt', 'r') as f: for line in f: print(line)` See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1478712/1762224).

Comment: You could try using grep as well if this doesn't need to be python

Answer (score 0):

When you `read` the file you read the whole thing into a string.

When you iterate over it you get one character at a time.

Try printing the lines:

```
for line in r:
     print line
```

And you'll get

```
1
2
3
5

5
6
8
7
5

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

You need to say:

```
for line in r.split('\n'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rearranging your code

```
f = open("wawi.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    if elementid in line: #put str(elementid) if your input is of type `int`
        print("elementid exists")
        break
```

Comment: it works but he says that 258311 is the same as 25831. So i tried with elementid == line but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer to a string THEN iterate over the lines in the file, checking if the current line matches the `elementid`.

```
elementid = 123456 # given
searchTerm = str(elementid)
with open('wawi.txt', 'r') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if searchTerm in line:
            print('elementid exists on line #{}'.format(index))
```

### Output

```
elementid exists on line #3
```

---

## Another approach

A more robust solution is to extract all numbers out of each line and find the number in said numbers. This will declare a match if the number exists anywhere in the current line.

### Method

```
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', line)   # extract all numbers
numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]  # map the numbers to int
found   = elementid in numbers       # check if exists
```

### Example

```
import re
elementid = 123456 # given
with open('wawi.txt', 'r') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if elementid in [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', line)]:
            print('elementid exists on line #{}'.format(index))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("wawi.txt", "r")

for lines in f:
    if "elementid" in lines:
        print "Elementid found!"
    else:
        print "No results!"
```