# Reading and Writing from files in python

Tags: python, file

I have created a text file in python and I am struggling to find out how to print certain lines from the text file in python. hope someone can help me. I know it has something to do with f.write or f.read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: read file line by line into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array)

Comment: You might have missed the part about [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
f = open("C:/file.txt", "r")  #name of file open in read mode

lines = f.readlines()   #split file into lines

print(lines[1])  #print line 2 from file
```

Comment: Thank you this has really helped

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.txt') as file_data:
     text = file_data.read()
```

if you are using *.json files good solution is:

```
data = json.loads(open('data.json').read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `with` keyword to automatically handle file closing after opening the file.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line #you can do whatever you want with the line here
```

This handles file closing even if your program breaks during execution. The other - manual way of doing the same is:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    print line
f.close()
```

But beware that closing here happens only after your loop is executed. See also this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1478712/3917730)